# how to pass parameters to a triggered function in google-app-script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, gmail-api

I have a array of recipients and a scheduled time at which the mail has to be sent. I am eager in knowing if there is someway to create a trigger to which i can pass these params(recipients)

```
function send_mail(recipients)
{
  var id = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId();
  for(i=0;i<recipients.length;i++)
 {
   var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id="+id+"&exportFormat=html";
   var param = 
    {
      method      : "get",
      headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
      muteHttpExceptions:true,
    };
   var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,param).getContentText();
   var raw = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe("Subject: Test\r\n" +
                                        "To:" +recipients[i]+"\r\n" +
                                        "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n" +
                                        html+"\r\n\r\n");
   var message = Gmail.newMessage();
   message.raw = raw;
   var sentMsg = Gmail.Users.Messages.send(message, recipients[i]);
 }
}
function schedule_mail(recipients,schedule)
{
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("send_mail").timeBased().at(schedule).create();
}
```

If params cannot be passed to a timeBased trigger, then is there any other work around?

Comment: I don't think that you can pass parameters to a trigger. Have you consider using [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) ?

Comment: How to manage the trigger if i store the variables in PropertiesService, like when should i create the trigger and how to delete the trigger after execution @Pierre-MarieRichard

Comment: You create your trigger and store your variables in PropertiesService. Then, you may add a piece of code in your function to take back the variables from PropertiesService. When the function has finished, you clear the trigger :
function delTrigger(){
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }
}
But this solution work only if you manipulate a few send

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this. But here is a workaround.
Note: This is just the instruction and not the actual code. Check my comments in code.

```
function send_mail(recipients)
{
  ............
  ............
}

function triggerHandler(e){
  var triggerId = e.triggerUid;
  //Iterate through all triggers and get the matching triggerId and corresponding recipient
  send_mail(recipient);
}

function schedule_mail(recipients,schedule)
{
  var trigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger("triggerHandler").timeBased().at(schedule).create();
  var ID = trigger.getUniqueId();
  //Save this ID against the recipient details in user properties
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Hari Das for the work around. It worked fine.

Comment: For those like me wondering what is "e", isn't it a function parameter ? Have a look at "Event objects" here : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events. Here is the gist : 

>When a trigger fires, Apps Script passes the function an event object as an argument, typically called e. The event object contains information about the context that caused the trigger to fire.